# Suppress PHP warning .using htaccess

Tags: php

I have a baby plan at hostgator and I need to suppress warnings. Could you hep me please?. I am trying

```
php_flag display_errors off
php_value error_reporting 0
```

Comment: Have you tried using a php.ini file? I wouldn't suppress the reporting, just displaying. Maybe this thread is useful, http://forums.hostgator.com/disabling-php-error-reporting-t32554.html.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
error_reporting(0);
@ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```